# "Find they're equal", is this correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Just stumble upon the headline of this article : **"Mathematicians Measure Infinities, and Find They're Equal"** ( [Source](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/mathematicians-measure-infinities-and-find-theyre-equal/) ), and it's messing with my head.

Is the usage correct?

If it's up to me, I would write it as "... and find them equal", or "... and find that they're equal".

Help me out here.

Comment: Headline writers typically leave out inessential words. Strictly speaking 'find that they're equal' would be more correct.

Comment: It's fine as is. The comma can also be removed.